# Get all occurrences of words between curly brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like:

```
This is a {demo} phrase made for {test}
```

I need to get

```
demo  
test
```

Note: My text can have more than one block of `{}`, not always two. Example:

```
This is a {demo} phrase made for {test} written in {English}
```

I used this expression `/{([^}]*)}/` with `preg_match` but it returns only the first word, not all words inside the text.

Answer (score 15):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
```

It's much the same as `preg_match`, with the following stipulations:

> Searches subject for all matches to the regular expression given in
>   pattern and puts them in matches in the order specified by flags.
>
> After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued
>   on from end of the last match.

Answer (score 11):

Your expression is correct, but you should be using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead to retrieve *all* matches. Here's a working example of what that would look like:

```
$s = 'This is a {demo} phrase made for {test}';

if (preg_match_all('/{([^}]*)}/', $s, $matches)) {
        echo join("\n", $matches[1]);
}
```

To also capture the positions of each match, you can pass `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` as the fourth parameter to `preg_match_all`. To use that, you can use the following example:

```
if (preg_match_all('/{([^}]*)}/', $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            echo "{$match[0]} occurs at position {$match[1]}\n";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the `{` and `}` are part of regex matching syntax, you need to escape these characters:

```
<?php
$text = <<<EOD
this {is} some text {from}
which I {may} want to {extract}
some words {between} brackets.
EOD;
preg_match_all("!\{(\w+)\}!", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

produces

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {is}
            [1] => {from}
            [2] => {may}
            [3] => {extract}
            [4] => {between}
        )
     ... etc ...
)
```

This example may be helpful to understand the use of curly brackets in regexes:

```
<?php
$str = 'abc212def3456gh34ij';
preg_match_all("!\d{3,}!", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 212
            [1] => 3456
        )
)
```

Note that '34' is excluded from the results because the `\d{3,}` requires a match of at least 3 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 0):

Matching portions between pair of braces using RegEx, is less better than using Stack for this purpose. Using RegEx would be something like «quick and dirty patch», but for parsing and processing input string you have to use a stack. Visit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29?) for the concept and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php?) for applying the same.